# Creating admins table separate in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-ui

I am creating a Laravel project for the users. Laravel has its own `laravel/ui` package, but I am creating its admin panel too, and I am a bit confused about what I should do for admins. Also, I am confused about the security for the admin panel. So there are 2 solutions in my mind:

1. Add a new column in the user's table named `status,` and if its value is admin, he can access the admin panel; otherwise, redirect to the homepage.
2. Create a separate admins table and improve `laravel/ui auth`. For that, I found documentation [here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel/).

What should I do? Even i have added `table prefix` for tables in `.env` & `config/database.php`. I am afraid that the hackers/users should not access the admin panel. And also, tell me if the table prefix is good for security, or should I remove the table prefix?

Comment: You should use same table with `status` column. If you validate all requests, it is not easy to hack. Anyway you store has value of passwords.

Comment: you same table but and add column of enum `role` and the enum contain `user` and `admin` then based on that you can create middleware check

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers. Please check the updated question, I have added the last line about `table prefix`

Comment: I think this is more a question of semantics. Do you consider an admin to be different from a user or do you consider an admin to be a special kind of user?

Comment: @apokryfos A special kind of user, I mean he has access to admin panel to  `create read update & delete the data`. But i am confused about the security and hackers, that's why i need a strong system, so one user/hackers can access admin panel except admins

Comment: I don't see how there's a difference between a new table and an additional "flag" in the existing table with respect to security. [authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization) allows you to set actions that only your admin can perform and add guards to those actions. the laravel permission package suggested in an answer is also a good alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I was just confused about the security, that's why i put the question here, so that you people can suggest me. Surely i am gonna use that `spatie laravel-permission package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the permission-roles system.

**https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction**

This is good decision for you. With well-configured routes no one wont have access in admin panel without access in data base.

For example, in panel page only admin have access:

```
Route::name('adminspace.')->group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
        
    Route::view('/panel', 'pages.panel');
});
```

Comment: You mean i just have add one column `role` or `status` in users table? and check in the admin pages that if the role value is `admin` then open the page otherwise redirect to homepage?

Comment: No, u need read docs in the link above. Or you can find the tutorial on YouTube by looking for "Spatie Laravel-permission tutorial"